# Firebase Firestore - differences between mobile and web SDK

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wonder where the differences between the SDK comes from.
For example, I have a list of news. I perform two operations on it: refresh and download the first or next offset.
When I am using a mobile SDK and I will call this for refreshing:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("news")
.whereEqualTo("categories.finance", true)
.whereEqualTo("locale", "pl")
.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
.limit(15)
.endAt(1518554580)
.get()
```

It will return the latest news. But if I will execute it on cloud functions:

```
admin.firestore().collection('news')
.where('categories.finance', '==', true)
.where('locale', '==', language)
.limit(15)
.orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
.endAt(1518554580)
.get()
```

I am getting an empty list.
The same applies to downloading offsets. Query looks like above with one difference - I am using startAfter(1518554580).

Why is this happening? Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Could you show the entire query, and not just the filtering parts?  You might be querying two different collections - it's impossible to tell here.  Also, it's not possible to tell here what `language` is here, but you've hard-coded it into the other.

Comment: What is the data type of `timestamp`?

Comment: @DougStevenson It's number - Long on android

Comment: If you don't filter and just to a simple `.get()` of the ref, are you able to get data in the Cloud Function? Just trying to make sure the query is the issue.

Comment: @JenPerson I checked it a moment ago, if I turn off the filters, the query returns the last 15 elements.

Answer (score 0):

I know why this is happening. 
For some reason, compound index with descending timestamp works for mobile, but for web it's working when index is ascending.
For this reason, I must have two indexes for each category.

Comment: Firestore is still a beta product, and it looks like you found a bug in the web SDK. I recommend [filing a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) so that this gets fixed soon and you won't need 2 indexes for each category.